# Counting occurrences of "hi" in a string, except where followed by "x"

Tags: java, strings, recursion

I already solved this one from [CodingBat](http://codingbat.com/prob/p143900), but I'm unsatisfied with my solution and I feel I could have made it much shorter. Most of the other recursion tasks could be solved by a one line conditional for the base case and a one line return statement usually using ternary operator. So, could I have made this any shorter or more readable?

> Given a string, compute recursively the number of times lowercase "hi" appears in the string, however do not count "hi" that have an 'x' immedately before them.

```
public int countHi2(String str) {
  if (str.length() <= 1) {
    return 0;
  }


  if (str.startsWith("x") && str.charAt(1) != 'x') {
    return countHi2(str.substring(2));
  }
  else if (str.startsWith("hi")) {
    return 1 + countHi2(str.substring(2));
    }
  else {
    return countHi2(str.substring(1));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't get much shorter than that. But some other improvements are possible.

The current algorithm uses `startswith` method to check for `x` and `hi`, and as such it advances by 1 or 2 characters at a time. This is inefficient.

Another performance issue is creating many temporary strings in the process (because of `substring`).

It would be better to use `indexOf` instead of `startswith`, which will allow you to jump multiple characters at a time. Another big improvement would be to avoid temporary string generation, by creating a helper function that tracks the position to check. Something like this:

```
public int countHi2(String str) {
    return countHi2(str, 0);
}

public int countHi2(String str, int start) {
    start = str.indexOf("hi", start);
    if (start == -1) {
        return 0;
    }

    int count = 0;
    if (start == 0 || str.charAt(start - 1) != 'x') {
        count++;
    }
    return count + countHi2(str, start + 2);
}
```